# Flutter project debugging is not Run in my vivo phone

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing a difficult problem now. Right now I can't do a flutter debug on my real Vivo-v2020 phone device. I've tried everything possible, but I still get this error and can't debug. However, the installed app works properly.
In my device everything is okay, Developer Mode ON, USB Debugging mode also ON
Any solution to this? Please help me... This is very important for me.

log:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on V2022 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Parameter format not correct -
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
I/flutter ( 4243): Observatory listening on ************************************
```

Answer (score 2):

Actullay i faced this issue in my realme mobiles and vivo mobiles

The way i found to get out of it is.Uninstalling the debugging application using adb command-it remove application from all users and it works fine again

command: adb uninstall com.example.packagename

replace it with our package name

Comment: Please describe more, How I can replace the package name?

Comment: check the package name in Androidmanifest.xml and run adb uninstall packagename

Comment: @Y.B.VamsidharReddy It is not working. Is there any workaround? I am stuck with splash screen

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem with my vivo-v2025. But I solved the issue by following a simple step.

First, you just run the app on your phone using debug mode as usual.
Then you will see an error as shown below:

```
  "   Launching lib/main.dart on V2025 in debug mode...
      ✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
      I/flutter (22675): Observatory listening on***************** "
```

After this, you just TERMINATE the program and start a fresh new run. The app will open. It worked in my case.

Posting an output image here .
[image]

Answer (score 1):

update to android 12 there must be resolved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

vivo now runs flutter, update to the latest may 1st 2022 patch. You need to upgrade your device by accepting the latest update.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).